# Call GitVersion from C#

Tags: c#, gitversion

I'm writing a Cake GIT plugin that shall calculate a SemVer with the help of [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I'm using the [GitVersion NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion/3.6.5) package, which delivers GitVersionCore.dll.

Can anyone give me hint how to use the Core.dll? It seems that it's not realy documented.

Or is the recommended way calling `GitVersion.exe` via `Process.Start` and fetch the ouput?

thx

Comment: You should post what you're exactly trying to achieve and what problems you're faced with in an actual attempt. If you're looking for best practices or how to use GitVersion probably best to check their documentation. Anyhow, those kinda of tools are mostly aimed at running from the command line in a CI/CD environment, you can probably use it successful to do it locally, but since you post no code, there is no help to be given here.

Comment: There is already a Cake GitVersion plugin: `#tool "nuget:?package=GitVersion.CommandLine"`. Maybe you can use it. GitVersion [page](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/nuget-library/) says that Nuget library is unstable and undocumented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use this Nuget you should check `GitVersion.ExecuteCore.ExecuteGitVersion` method. Check sources in `ExecuteCore.cs` line `28`

The signature is: `public VersionVariables ExecuteGitVersion(string targetUrl, string dynamicRepositoryLocation, Authentication authentication, string targetBranch, bool noFetch, string workingDirectory, string commitId, Config overrideConfig = null, bool noCache = false, bool noNormalize = false)`